# Hide post title when single post with specific category

Tags: posts

May I know is there a way I can show my blog post title under the below condition?

```
<header class="single-header">
  <?php if(is_singular('post') && (!is_category('campaign-post'))) : ?>
   <h2 class="page-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
</header>
```

I have a few different categories, which I have created within Posts. One of it (campaign-post), I wish not to show the post title. So I have written the above condition. Unfortunately, no luck. The title still showing.

Can anyone show some clue how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
!is_category('campaign-post')
```

I think it's

```
!in_category('campaign-post')
```

---

[`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) is used within Archives pages, when it's in WP Query. Like your viewing a category archive page, and you're asking: *is this the category queried*.

[`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) (which uses [`has_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) which then uses [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) which then uses [`is_object_in_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_object_in_term/)) relates to single posts, asking: *does this post have this term*.